# Retrieve custom data-* attributes value in React Component(without event)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, custom-data-attribute

I have 2 questions with respective re-usable React Components.

1. I would like to have to React Component which should take the `props` object from the `data-` attribute from the HTML, this should happen onload instead of event. The examples shown in the React Docs use props within the `ReactDOM.render` method. I couldn't find an example where we retrieve props from `data` attributes.
2. I would also like to reuse the React Component without duplicating the `ReactDOM.render`, instead just change the props and mount the component(s) based on their class name.

[Sample Example] I have the HTML markup as,

```
<div class="blog" id="Politics" data-title="Political Science"></div>
<p>
Some description text..
</p>
<div class="blog" id="Economics" data-title="World Economy"></div>
```

The React Component is,

```
var propTitle = {
  'title': getTitle() //Function to retrieve data-title from respective component.
};
var Blog = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <h3>
        {this.props.blogtitle} 
      </h3>
    )
  }
}); 

ReactDOM.render(<Blog blogtitle={propTitle.title}/>,document.querySelectorAll('.blog'));
```

For convenience, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aleem86s/qpkjvbea/4/) is here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var blogs = document.querySelectorAll('.blog');
for(var i = 0; i < blogs.length; i++){
    createComponent(blogs[i]);
}

function createComponent(blog){
    ReactDOM.render(<Blog blogtitle={blog.dataset.title} />, blog)
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rtLux0f6/1/